# why is 8 Bytes incrementation in ESP register needed?

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention

Recently I saw a small assembly code,but I am not quite clear of the reason that the incrementation of esp register is needed.

Please review the code below:

```
.section .data
values:
.int 21,15,23,44,1,2,54,24,33,2

output:
.asciz "The number is %d\n"
.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
nop
movl %9,%edi

loop:
pushl values(,%edi,4)
pushl output
call printf
add $8,%esp
dec %edi
jnz loop
movl $1,eax
movl $0,%ebx
int $0x80
```

Question:
a)After "`pushl values(,%edi,4)`"(when `%edi` is equal 9) and "`pushl output`",there are "`2`" and  "The number is `%d\n`" in stack and the total bytes ,I think,should be 4+18=22 bytes. Why should 8 bytes incrementation be added after "`call printf`"?

b)Is it necessary to make incrementation 8 bytes in esp register,which position 
should the `%esp` point to?(We assume before `pushl values(,%edi,4)`...,the address of esp is N,after "2" is pressed in the stack,the position which esp points to is N-4.  )

Comment: There are 2 arguments pushed, each 4 bytes. Note it's not the string placed on the stack, just its address. In fact the correct at&t syntax for that is `pushl $output`, your code would just put the first 4 bytes on the stack and should crash.

Comment: Thanks very much,it is clear.If the code part is changed to String,whether should I use "add $22,%esp" to clear up the stack?Is that correct?

Comment: Not sure what the change is, but you should keep stack pointer aligned to 4 bytes by convention (although the cpu does not strictly require it) so 22 should never happen. The prototype is `printf(const char*, ...)` so the first argument is a pointer.

Comment: `printf` is variadic and can't know how many arguments were pushed.
So the caller needs to clean the stack: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up

Comment: Thanks a lot,very helpful idear.